# Assign a separate html page to each user in django admin

Tags: python, html, django, django-admin

I have 15 users in my django model and they are displayed on an html page by using the html code:

```html
{% for user in users %}

<h3>{{ user.get_full_name }}</h3>

{% endfor %}
```

[image]
I want for each user to have a different html page. I would like for the name of the user to be a hyperlink and when you click on the link, it will go to the html page of that user's page.

views.py:

```
def user1(request):
if request.method =='POST':

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('user1')
else:
    return render(request, 'accounts/user1.html')

def user2(request):
if request.method =='POST':

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('user2')
else:
    return render(request, 'accounts/user2.html')
```

models.py:

```
 class User(models.Model):


user = models.OneToOneField("auth.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
player_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
jersey_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
position = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
height = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
weight = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
grade = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
headshot = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

How do I connect each user in the "for users" with their own html page. Since I am not writing out every user manually and adding a  tag, I am confused on how to give each user a separate html page using this format. I tried to use this code to give each user a separate profile page.

views.py:

```
 def view_profile(request, pk=None):
 if pk:
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
else:
    user = request.user

args = {'user': user}
return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)
```

Comment: But why would you have separate views and templates for each user? Surely you just have a standard view that displays a user's information on a standard template.

Comment: Well, the reason I will have separate views is because each user will different data. For example, I am creating a basketball stats application. Each user will have completely different set of stats which is over a 1000 metrics. I am unaware on how to update stats on each user, so I decided to give them separate html page. Any suggestions?

Comment: But this doesn't make sense. How are you modelling and storing that data? Surely you don't have a separate model for each user; so you don't need separate views or templates.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am new to django. So yes, you are correct. I have one model for users. This displays all of the player's information. I attached a picture of how the user's are displayed. I am using the django-admin to input the user information. But I want each user to have their own profile page, but I do not want them to display the same basketball stats. They all will have completely different profile pages.